# What's a clever way to find all nested classes in a C# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, search, project, nested-class

Doing some project clean up, and rather than just relying on my human eyes to find all nested classes does anyone know of a clever way I can use the computer to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that??? Nested classes are great, you can make them *private*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to see a listing then Object Browser should provide you a good overview of inner classes.  They would be the only qualified names listed.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, [Type.GetNestedTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) should work just fine to do that programmatically. Or is that not your question?

Comment: Actually that might work if I can write a quick method that will cycle all the classes in the project and output something for each one from this GetNestedTypes call.

Comment: +1 Its the same thing I was thinking. `GetNestedTypes` should be just what you need Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may be useful.

```
public static class TypeExplorer
{
    public static string GetTypeTree<T>()
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        GetTypeTree(typeof(T), stringBuilder, 0);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static void GetTypeTree(Type type, StringBuilder stringBuilder, int nestingLevel)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(new string(' ', nestingLevel) + type.Name);

        nestingLevel++;

        foreach (var nestedType in type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            GetTypeTree(nestedType, stringBuilder, nestingLevel);
        }
    }
}
```